# How to add a title and modify the color palette in a ggraph plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggraph

I am working with packages `see` and `ggraph` in `R` to plot a correlation graph but I can't add the title of the plot and I can't change the colour palette. The MWE provided is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse) # for `%>%` and probably others
library(see) # for plotting
library(ggraph) # needs to be loaded
library(correlation) # obviously for `correlation`, which I noticed was installed as a dependency of pkg:see but apparently not loaded with it.

mtcars %>% 
correlation(partial = TRUE) %>% 
plot()
```

Comment: From what package is `correlation()`?

Comment: May be worth going with `cor()` and `ggcorrplot()`, @Jose, unless your task requires your listed packages.

Comment: Have you done any searching on how to add a title to a ggplot object? Have you cone any searching on how to modify a color palett on a ggplot object?

Comment: I did but since it is a predetermined package I couldn't find how to modify the colour palette or the layout for the title, etc...properly in the vignette. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the edge color scale, you need to use one of the `scale_edge_color*` functions from ggraph:

```r
library(correlation)
library(ggraph)
library(ggplot2)

p <- plot(correlation(mtcars, partial = TRUE)) +
  scale_edge_color_gradientn(colours = c("red3", "gray90", "green4")) +
  ggtitle("Partial correlation of mtcars dataset") +
  coord_equal(clip = "off")

p
```

[image]

There seem to be limited options to change the fixed aesthetic parameters from within the plotting function, but you can change the layers the the produced ggplot object. You can also change theme elements as usual in a ggplot:

```r
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- "navy"
p$layers[[3]]$aes_params$size <- 6

p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "skyblue"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will get you close to what you want, Jose:

```
cor_matrix <- cor(mtcars, method='pearson',use='complete.obs')
ggcorrplot(cor_matrix, method = c("square"), type = c("full"), 
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_minimal, 
           title = "Practice Title", show.legend = TRUE, 
           legend.title = "Corr", 
           show.diag = FALSE, outline.color = "gray", hc.order = TRUE, 
           lab = TRUE, 
           lab_col = "black", 
           lab_size = 2, tl.cex = 10, tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45, digits = 2) + 
  theme(
   legend.key.width = unit(.6, "cm"),   #to resize legend
   legend.key.height = unit(1.4, "cm"),
  )
```